# Проблема с password_verify постоянно выводит false при вводе пароля

Tags: php

Прошу помощи не работает `password_verify` постоянно выдаёт `echo "Пароль не совпадает";`

```
            <?php
                require_once 'lib/db_connect.php';

                if (isset($_REQUEST['doGo'])) {
    
                    if (!$_REQUEST['login']) {
                        $error = 'Введите логин';
                    }
                    // Проверяет пароль
                    if (!$_REQUEST['pass']) {
                        $error = 'Введите пароль';
                    }

                    if (!$error) {
                        $login = $_REQUEST['login'];
                        $pass = $_REQUEST['pass'];

                        if ($result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT `passwd`, `id сотрудника` FROM `сотрудники` WHERE `login`='" . $login . "'")) {
                            while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ){ 
                                if ($row['id сотрудника']) {
                                    if (password_verify($pass, $result['passwd'])) {
                                        echo "Вы вошли";
                                        exit;
                                    } else {
                                        echo "Пароль не совпадает";
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    echo "Введён неверный логин";
                                }
                            } 
                        }
                    } else {
                        echo $error;
                    }
                }
            ?>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы полностью неправильно используете password_verify, читайте документацию https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.password-hash.php | https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.password-verify.php

Answer (score -1):

Потому что почитайте внимательно описание функции password_verify. В мануале написано, что она проверяет, соответствует ли пароль хешу. А вы в качестве параметров подсовываете сырые пароли, естественно она возвращает false. В вашем случае будет просто `if ($pass == result['passwd'])`

Но хранить пароли в открытом виде - очень плохая практика. Как минимум можно хранить md5 хэши паролей

Comment: Какие ещё "md5 хэши паролей"?!

Comment: @Ипатьев ну и за что минус? Ответ есть? Есть, по делу. Про md5 что смущает? Совет по хранению паролей не в открытом виде тоже дельный, лучше, чем текущая реализация. Вам бы лишь минусы ставить

Comment: @Crasher смущает то, что md5 нихрена не защищает и с радужными таблицами вскрывается вмиг. Зачем вредные советы людям даёте?

Comment: а как хешировать по md5 разясните по синтаксису

Comment: @BaZumBa никак, хешировать пароли с помощью md5 ни в коем случае нельзя, хешируйте через password_hash

Comment: @andreymal вот, пожалуйста, радужными таблицами, перебором, или еще как расшифруйте, раз все так просто и быстро 71c145f6c83932fc39bd5bdef09c458e

Comment: @Crasher если вы мне оплатите покупку выполняющего перебор оборудования, то расшифрую. Я не злоумышленник, чтобы держать ферму для вскрытия md5 в промышленных масштабах